# Cannot implicitly convert type ConsoleSandbox.StudentName to int

Tags: c#, .net

Ok I am new to this and I have a simple question. I have a class

```
public class StudentName
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

And in the main method Im trying to call something like :

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int number = 123;
        var result = number;

        if (number.Equals(123))
        {
            result = new StudentName
            {
                FirstName = "Jurand",
                LastName = "Kowalsky",
                ID = 183
            };
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The reason I do not assign object to another var is that sometimes I have different methods overloads that take different parameters.

Is there a way to convert int to object? Or any way to do it that matter?

Comment: You can always find a way to shoot yourself on your feet. Why do you want to make such a silly thing? There is a lot of difference between an integer and a object reference. Stay safe and use the proper variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two lines

```
int number = 123;
var result = number;
```

tell the compiler that `result` is of type `int`.  That is set *at compile time*.

This line

```
result = new StudentName
```

attempts to assign a `StudentName` to result.  This can not work, because it already has the type `int`.

While you *can* first assign an integer and then a StudentName to the same variable by changing its type to object

```
object result = number;
```

that smells of bad program design.

Note that this line

```
System.Console.WriteLine(result);
```

will work if `result` is still an integer.  If you change it to object, it will just print out System.Object (or something very similar).  If you end up changing your program design such that you use the type StudentName, you can override ToString() in that class to provide meaningful output, e.g.

```
public class StudentName
{
    /* Rest of the class here */
    public override ToString()
    {
       return FirstName + " " + LastName + " ID: " + ID;
    }
}
```

> The reason I do not assign object to another var is that sometimes I have different methods overloads that take different parameters.

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but have a look at [C# Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  They allow you to write code once that can work for a wide range of types, and then specify the exact type where you use the generic class.

Answer (score 2):

Change `var result = number;` to `object result = number;`.

Using `var` doesn't mean that you can switch the type of the variable during runtime, it simply means that the compiler determines the type of the variable at compile time. Since you had an `int` assigned to result, it typed result as an `int`. When you tried to assign a `StudentName` to that variable, it threw an exception because it couldn't convert a `StudentName` to an `int`.

Since all objects inherit from `object`, making `result` an object type should resolve the issue.

Comment: Although technically you're right, I don't think you're doing the OP a favor suggesting the use of `object` for known types. What if he wants to compare the boxed `int` to another `int`?

Comment: I think that you're right that this reeks of other issues, however, I have no idea what the OP is trying to accomplish. I just tried to answer his actual question with what limited information was provided.

Answer (score 1):

Even though with `var` you no longer have to declare your variable with a type, the compiler still "assigns" a type to it. You can't reuse any variable for a different type.

I don't understand your argument that different method overloads prevent you from using a different variable. Reusing variables for different things makes your code very unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the others: Change var into the type you really want to use. That's how you better learn to understand about types.

var is necessary for some new features in new .NET versions - but first you should learn about the basics.

var can be useful with very long classnames, when you just initialize an object once:

```
BufferedFileInputStream myStream = new BufferedFileInputStream;
```

vs.

```
var myStream = new BufferedFileInputStream;
```

This is just a shortcut for better reading. You should never use myStream for anything else. If you do, it is a code smell.